# Database Link ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: streaming, dblink

Please help with this database link error i have been struggling for 2 days, Btw, fix this with get my oracle stream works. Stream error: WAITING FOR INACTIVE DEQUEUERS". Checked problem comes from db-link, so here is the problem:

```
--user: sys
--environmentL appuat1
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK "ANAUAT0" USING 'anauat0

--user: STRMADMIN_FORM
--environmentL appuat1

CREATE DATABASE LINK ANAUAT0
  CONNECT TO "STRMADMIN_FORM" IDENTIFIED BY "STRMADMIN_FORM"
  USING 'anauat0';

--user: STRMADMIN_FORM
--environmentL appuat1
select * from STRMADMIN_FORM.Table@'anauat0;
```

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
ORA-02063: preceding line from ANAUAT0
01017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"

**Question1: Given that username & password are correct, what is the problem?**

```
--user: SYS
--environmentL appuat1
select * from STRMADMIN_FORM.Table@'anauat0;
```

ERROR:
ORA-28000: the account is locked
ORA-02063: preceding line from ANAUAT0
28000. 00000 -  "the account is locked"
*Cause:    The user has entered wrong password consequently for maximum
           number of times specified by the user's profile parameter
           FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, or the DBA has locked the account
*Action:   Wait for PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME or contact DBA

**Question 2: Checked no account are locked, what is locked?**

From the other way round can select table using opposit direction Db-link.

update: a trade of to prevent error is to use tns information :

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK "ANAUAT0"
  CONNECT TO "STRMADMIN_ADM" IDENTIFIED BY  "STRMADMIN_ADM"
  USING '(DESCRIPTION=
    (ADDRESS=
      (PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=xx.xx.xx.xxx)
      (PORT=1521)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA=
      (SERVICE_NAME=anauat0)
    )
  )';
```

But using service name is what I want to do. Obviously service name is cause of problem (the service name is working fine)
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Somebody added a same name TNS on the server cause comflict. 
Thanks!